# Search for a unique username using firestore and Flutter efficiency

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I used Firebase cloud-firestore to check if the username is unique or exists in firestore cloud using this code and it work correctly until now,but What happened if I have more than 10000 username to check using this code ?

So How much time need to check the database ? and Do you suggest using algolia or elasticSearch instead .

````
    final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
        .collection('check_username')
        .where('username', isEqualTo: userNameController.text.toLowerCase())
        .limit(1)
        .getDocuments());
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.documents;
    if (documents.length == 1) {
      print("UserName Already Exits");
      setState(() {
        _userExist = documents.length == 1;
      });
    } else {
      print("UserName is Available");
      setState(() {
        _userExist = documents.length == 1;
      });
    }```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the fun (and quite unique) tricks of Firestore is that the performance of a read operation does not depend on the number of documents in the collection. Instead it *only* depends on the amount of data you read.

So in your query you're retrieving a single document:

```
final QuerySnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
    .collection('check_username')
    .where('username', isEqualTo: userNameController.text.toLowerCase())
    .limit(1)
```

For the performance it doesn't matter if there are 100 documents in `check_username`, 100,000 documents, or 100,000,000 documents, the performance will always be the same.

---

That said, I'd recommend using the username itself as the key in this collection. That automatically ensures that there can be only a single document for each username, as document IDs must be unique within their collection.

So if you use the username as the document ID, the check becomes:

```
final DocumentSnapshot result = await Future.value(Firestore.instance
    .collection('check_username')
    .document(userNameController.text.toLowerCase())
    .get());
if (result.exists) {
  print("UserName Already Exits");
} else {
  print("UserName is Available");
}
setState(() {
  _userExist = result.exists;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, Frank! When using the username as the document ID, is it correct/secure to then allow updates to the document if resource.id == userId?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63527201/best-practices-for-firestore-rules-when-using-a-username-rather-than-the-auto-g